# How to pass onclick function values to ajax post method without refresh page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my onclick function. When I click it the php values should save in database.

```
<div class="startup-like">
<label class="toggler toggler-danger">
<input type="checkbox"     onclick="return favadd(<?php echo $favblogid;?>,<?php echo $b;?>,<?php echo $type_id;?>,<?php echo $lang_id;?>);">
<i class="fa fa-bookmark" title="Save" id="toptip"></i>
</label>
</div>
```

and this is my script for the onclick function.

```
 <script>
     function favadd(val,val2,val3,val4)
     {

         var blog_id=val;
        var userid=val2;
       var catid=val3;
        var lang=val4;

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "startuparticle_save.php",

             data: {
             fav_blogid: blog_id,
           fav_user_id: userid,
              cat_id:catid,
              langid:lang

             },
           success: function (value) {

         }
         });

     }
  </script>
```

I want to pass the values without refresh the page.

Comment: I don't think this code will refresh your page.
Do you have any other code in this function ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#MyButton").click(function() {
    alert('clicked')
    $("#refresh_div").load(" #refresh_div> *`enter code here`");
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: is it ok for me

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
 function favadd(val,val2,val3,val4)
 {

     var blog_id=val;
    var userid=val2;
   var catid=val3;
    var lang=val4;

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "startuparticle_save.php",

         data: {
         fav_blogid: blog_id,
       fav_user_id: userid,
          cat_id:catid,
          langid:lang

         },
       success: function (value) {
       "$("#your div id").load(" #your div id> ");"
     }
     });

 }
</script>
```